# Vim option value contains error message when editing ruby files, Gem.all_load_paths

Tags: ruby, vim

When editing ruby, some files but not all are garbled when editing in vim.

Inspecting the options with `:set`, I discovered that there is some magic done to produce one of the option values, and something went wrong with the magic and there is an error or warning message where the option value should be.  That may be causing side effects.

The method throwing the error is `Gem.all_load_paths`, and it happens regardless of whether I use ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2, whether I use `rvm` or system `ruby`.  Using Ubuntu 11.10

I've tried setting the `omnifunc` option to `nil`, but that doesn't solve the problem;  it seems to be a different option producing this value.  The plugins I'm using can be seen below.

```
:set
--- Options ---
  autoindent          comments=:#         history=50          keywordprg=ri       scroll=29           suffixesadd=.rb     ttyfast
  backup              filetype=ruby       hlsearch            mouse=a             shiftwidth=2        syntax=ruby         ttymouse=xterm2
  backupdir=~/.tmp    helplang=en         incsearch           ruler               showcmd             tabstop=2
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  balloonexpr=RubyBalloonexpr()
  commentstring=# %s
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  formatoptions=croql
  include=^\s*\<\(load\|w*require\)\>
  includeexpr=substitute(substitute(v:fname,'::','/','g'),'$','.rb','')
  indentexpr=GetRubyIndent()
  indentkeys=0{,0},0),0],!^F,o,O,e,=end,=elsif,=when,=ensure,=rescue,==begin,==end
  omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete                                                                                                                              f
rom ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:62:in `all_load_paths'^@^Ifrom -e:1^@1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:62:in `send'^@^I
  printoptions=paper:letter                                                                                                                                   /
after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/afterm,~/.vim/bundle/vim-rails,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim73,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles
  suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc
```

Comment: The option that contains the offending value is the `path` option. I spent more time ruling out possible causes, removing plugins, etc.  The output of `:set` has changed now, and all plugins back in place.  I think opening and closing and opening my shell was the most recent think I did before noticing the change.  The editor is usable now, and the files don't become hopelessly garbled.  However, within the value of `path`, there is still a notice that Gem.all_load_paths is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same thing today after updating from Snapshot 63 to Snapshot 64 of MacVim. It's an ugly hack, but I found the offending line (79) in `MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin/ruby.vim` and removed the reference to `Gem.all_load_paths`, which is deprecated with no replacement.

I've posted [a diff of my gist](https://gist.github.com/1712313) that gets me going. It's not clear to me at this point if this is a bug to be reported against MacVim or Vim.

Answer (score 1):

I built on @pbyme a little bit and actually found the new way to do it.  With my current setup, it's even pulling in some local gems brought in by bundler.

The key is replacing `all_load_paths` with `Specification.map(&:lib_dirs_glob)`

`MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin/ruby.vim`

```
79c79
<     let s:code = "print ($: + begin; require %q{rubygems}; Gem.all_load_paths.sort.uniq; rescue LoadError; []; end).join(%q{,})"
---
>     let s:code = "print ($: + begin; require %q{rubygems}; Gem::Specification.map(&:lib_dirs_glob).sort.uniq;  rescue LoadError; []; end).join(%q{,})"
```